# Are exercises for muscle gain the only way to increase weight in men?

Tags: weight-gain

People who are interested in weight gain generally achieve it by gaining muscle weight by doing weight lifting exercises, etc.

Can weight-gain be achieved after the age of 28 by increasing bone weight or by some other means of physical exercise, increasing the weight without any gain in muscles?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not fitness related (at least not as far as I can tell from the question)

Comment: Means, is it an elementary question or falls under common sense? Will it become on topic if there are some edits?

Comment: Yeah, of course. If you explain *how* this is fitness related to you it can be on-topic.

Comment: Is this a purely academic question? If you want to put this into practice, perhaps really think about your goal (e.g. looking a certain way) and ask how to achieve it instead. This sound to me a bit like something went wrong somewhere, maybe a misunderstanding. E.g. do you know that with a shirt on, you will not really be able to tell if you gained 20 pounds in muscle mass? You won't become a monster like your average competitive steroid user by gaining some muscle

Answer (score 4):

Exercise does have a very important role in both stopping the loss of bone mass and density and in increasing bone mass and density, as described in (among other papers) [The effects of progressive resistance training on bone density](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9927006) if you'd like to read up on it.

That said, generally someone's skeletal mass composes about 15% of their total body mass, so any increases on the scale are likely to be modest.

Comment: To expand - A 220 lb (100 kg) person has about 33 lbs (15 kg) in bone mass. A 10% increase in that would be ~ 3 lbs. Very small difference.